# How to add and remove an existing custom keyboard extension to and from a Xcode project?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I would like to know how to add an existing custom keyboard extension to a Xcode project?

Also, how to remove completely a custom keyboard extension from a project?

I don't know how to add/or remove targets in a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to magically add an existing custom extension.

(Just add keyboard extension target & copy/paste the files.)

How to remove is like this.

[image]

Select the project file.

[image]

Delete the Target.

[image]

Manage Schemes...

[image]

Delete the Schemes

[image]

Finally Delete the files.

It is over!

Comment: Thank you for the delete method. About the adding, I also followed what you said. But when I have a lot of things related to Info.plist, it's difficult to re-edit it again. Is it possible to copy and overwrite the Info.plist file? Because last time, I messed up my project and it's not a good idea to do so.

Comment: Info.plist can edited like text by (mouse right click on file, open-as, source code). You can copy from the existing one

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it is the best solution to edit the plist. Unless I know where to copy and paste.

Comment: Actually there are 18 plist keys in the keyboard-extension plist. But among them,  NSExtension and Bundle things are important